# How to change the schema and name for intermediary table generated from relationships

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have some entities/tables which I would like to place together in a schema. The intermediary tables from ManyToMany relationships are being generated in the public schema. How do I change the name and schema for the generated table?

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "my_schema")
public class AnotherEntity {}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "my_schema")
public class MyEntity {
    @ManyToMany
    private List<AnotherEntity> entityRelationship;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotate the relationship with [`@JoinTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html):

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "my_schema")
public class MyEntity {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="my_intermediary_table", schema="my_schema")
    private List<AnotherEntity> entityRelationship;
}
```